# Communication Between Bukkit Plugins on Separate Server

Tags: java, sockets, minecraft, bukkit, bungeecord

I was wondering if there is way to have two of the same bukkit (Minecraft) plugins communicate over something like Socket?

What I would like to do is if someone executes a command, that command will then be executed and then sent to the other server and executed there, and vice versa.

EX:
/broadcast {Message}
Then both servers will broadcast that message.

I'm not a Java expert, I actually just started a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution would to use something like [BungeeCord](http://www.spigotmc.org/threads/1-7-2-bungeecord.392/)

Plugins for server-chat sync can be found under the [resources section](http://www.spigotmc.org/resources/)
The spigot community is great, and you can ask many more minecraft related questions on their forums.

Comment: Built into bungee is a command known as /alert. It will broadcast a message on all servers.